# have duplicate logging python flask

Tags: python, logging

here is my config file
import logging
import logging.config

class HealthCheckFilter(logging.Filter):

```
def filter(self, record):

    return "health" not in record.getMessage()
```

mine_config = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'filters': {
'HealthCheckFilter': {'()': HealthCheckFilter}
},
'formatters': {'default': {
'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
}},
'handlers': {
'console': {
'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
'level': 'INFO',
'formatter': 'default',
'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',

```
        'filters': ['HealthCheckFilter']
    },
},
'root': {
    'level': "INFO",
    'handlers': ['console']
},
'loggers': {
    'myCustomLogger': {
        'level': "INFO",
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': False
    }
}
```

}
logging.config.dictConfig(mine_config)